# Uniform distribution over a triangle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

The two dimensional random variable is uniformly distributed over the triangle $A(0,0), B(4,0), C(2,2)$

1) Calculate for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^²$ the respective value of the density function $f(x,y)$.

2) Calculate the probability $P(X \leq 3, Y \leq 1)$

for 1) I tried to use the formulas for the triangular distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution, however we are two dimensional here. In the "solution"  it is stated, that one should solely calculate the area of the triangle to yield $f(x,y)$?! But I do not really understand this.

2) I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{1}\int_{-\infty}^{3}f(x,y) dx dy$, so I would need the result from (1) to calculate this.

Comment: Inside the triangle the density is constant (uniform) and outside it is $0$.   So the total probability is the integral of the density over the triangle, which is therefore the constant times the area of the triangle.  Since this integral is $1$, the constant must be the reciprocal of the area i.e. $\frac14$

Comment: @Henry: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area inside the triangle is 4 so the joint density is the following

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{(0;2)}(y)\mathbb{1}_{(y;y+4)}(x)$$

The knowlegde of this function in NOT necessary to answer to point 2)

In fact, to calculate the requested probability it is enough to look at the draw

[image]

And calculate the probabilty as the ratio of Purple area on the triangle area, say

$$\mathbb{P}[X \leq 3; Y \leq 1]=\frac{(\frac{1}{2}+2)}{4}=\frac{5}{8}$$

EDIT: answering to the latest comment of the O.P.

You can solve the same probability using the integral; of course you have always to integrate in the purlple area

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1dy \int_y^3 dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1[3-y]dy=\frac{5}{8}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the diagramm, and for point 2) you divided $(\frac{1}{2}+2)$ by $4$ because  $f(x,y)$ was $4$, right? but would (2) also work with the integral (I know your solution is much easier)

Comment: @xxPxx  : I divided by 4 because of the areas ratio. If you want to think in terms of density you have to multiply $(\frac{1}{2}+2)$ by $\frac {1}{4}$ because $f(x,y)=\frac {1}{4}$. Yes, with the integral you will get the same result

Comment: so the integral over $$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{(0;2)}(y)\mathbb{1}_{(y;y+4)}(x)$$ would be $\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2} \int_{y}^{y+4} 1 dxdy$ however for some reason, I do not the get same result (5/8) with this? Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @xxPxx : I edited my answer showing the calculation with the integral

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything is clear :)